# vector handling displaying output

Tags: c++, vector, cout

Vector data: Mary Daryl Cherry

Mary vector position[0]

Daryl vector position[1]

Cherry vector position[2]

Vector size: 3

Vector name: data

---

No need for Mary [ if vector[0], then display vector[1] and vector[2])

Scene 0:  Daryl is on Scene_0 Cherry is on Scene_0

---

No need for Daryl ( if vector[1], then display vector[0] and vector[2])

Scene 1: Mary is on Scene_1  Cherry is on Scene_1

---

No need for cherry( if vector[2], then display vector[0] and vector[1])

Scene 2:

Mary is on Scene_2 Daryl is on Scene_2

---

How do i display at such above? It seems kinda hard to display

```
data.erase(data.begin());

for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
{

    cout<<data[i]<<is on Scene_[i];

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
cout << data[i] << " is on Scene_" << i;
```

Comment: How do i do that it only display selective data? Like if its data[0] then display data[1] and data[2]

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, but you can use `if` statements to do things based on conditions. Check out http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/ :)

Comment: i re-edit the question, it should be clearer now. i try using if loop. but got stuck with it

Comment: Well, one way is to have a second inner loop that goes through the data as well, and displays all the items that aren't the current item, e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++ i) { for (int j = 0; j < data.size(); ++ j) { if (i != j) { /* display data */ } } }`

Answer (score 2):

For you problem, I think an inner loop can do easily the problem :

```
unsigned int size = data.size();
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
{
    for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < size; j++ )
    {
        if ( i != j )
        {
            cout << data[j] << " is on Scene_" << i;
        }
    }
}
```

You can see it working here : http://ideone.com/oYEIHY.

Maybe you should look at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/, because you seem not very familiar with the structures. For example, the `if` statement is a loop...